# How to stop draggable from being dragged beyond a certain position?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a bar that's supposed to portray time and under this bar I've positioned two draggable markers, one of them signifying the starting time and the other signifying ending time. Unfortunately it would seem very crude if you could drag the ending time marker to the left of the starting time marker, because we must have start time <= end time. I have been trying this [joern.zae...](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/trying-to-manipulate-the-position-of-a-draggable-mid-drag-doesn-t-seem-to-work#14737000000849001) . Instead of minus equals I found out that I need to have just equals though. But the solution doesn't work, instead the draggable just flickers.

In summary, I need the draggable to stop when it reaches a certain position on the x axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For draggables, you'd want to look at jQuery UI's samples [on constraining movement](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement).

From what it sounds like though, you're implementing a double handle slider bar, so you might want to [look jQuery UI's slider demos instead](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range).

Comment: Thanks! It works! As for the slider demos I think their ugly that's why I'm wheeling my own. This works: marker.draggable('option','containment',[250,0,500,0]), if the marker is initialized to be contained in parent the above code makes the marker stay in x=[250,500].

Comment: Cool! Glad to know you've got it running great. :D